# How do I pass values from child component to parent component without explicitly using events?

Tags: angular

Suppose I have two components, the parent `A` and a nested child `B`. I want to bind the `aVal` field of `A` to `bVal` field of `B` so that `aVal` is set to the value of `bVal` whenever `bVal` value changes. I know I can do it using `EventEmitter` and issuing an event whenever `bVal` changes but I do not want to explicitly care about events, I just want simple value binding. Is it even possible?

Parent component:

```
import {Component, Output} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'a',
  template: '<b></b>'
})
export class A {
  @Output() aVal: string;
}
```

Child component:

```
import {Component, Output} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'b',
  template: '<input [(ngModel)]="bVal"/>'
})
export class B {
  @Output() bVal: string;
}
```

I imagine the binding could look like `<b (bVal)="aVal"></b>` but it does not work.

---

### UPDATE

I decided that the best I can do is the following. It is quite clear and lets me ignore dealing with events as much as possible.

Parent component:

```
import {Component, Output} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'a',
  template: '<b (bValChange)="aVal=b.bVal" #b></b>'
})
export class A {
  @Output() aVal: string;
}
```

Child component:

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'b',
  template: '<input [(ngModel)]="bVal" (ngModelChange)="bValChange.emit()"/>'
})
export class B {
  bValChange: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
  bVal: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A service of some type (a factory makes sense) can be injected into both components and then bound to to a component variable. It's an expensive solution, but as I understand, Angular2 is built this way to prevent data in one modules/component from reaching data in others. This is for security and to ensure that unintended communication between components does not happen.

Also, the `Output()` Decorator can uses to emit an event with the desire value attached. here is a [concise example](http://learnangular2.com/outputs/)

Answer (score 1):

In A make the `aVal` a member (not an output)

```
aVal: string;
```

In B make the `bVal` and input:

```
@Input() bVal: string;
```

That should do it.

Btw, `(bVal)="aVal"` will not work. The `(someChangeOutput)`="handler($event)"` required a handler, and not a member/value

Comment: I do not understand how your solution applies to my case. I want `bVal` to be assigned to `aVal`, not the opposite.

Comment: Because you pass to B the variable you want to manipulate (aVal) which is locally named bVal. Every change you make in B to bVal (which is actually aVal) will reflect in aVal. If this doesn't work, try passing an object: aVal: any = {value: 'xxx'}, @Input() bVal: any; and in your template: <input [(ngModel)]="bVal.value"